# Оптимизация кода через указатель на функцию

Tags: c++, ооп

Как лучше вынести код в отдельную функцию в методе Search()? Пробовала сделать через указатель на функцию, но в указатель на функцию базового класса нельзя присваивать указатель на функцию производного класса.

```
enum DeviceCharacteristics
{
    SPEED,
    SPINDLESPEED,
    WRITESPEED
};

class DataStorageDevice
{
};

class USB : public DataStorageDevice
{
private:
    size_t m_speed;

public:
    string GetSpeed()
    {
        return to_string(m_speed);
    }
};

class DVD : public DataStorageDevice
{
private:
    size_t m_spindleSpeed;

public:
    string GetSpindleSpeed() const
    {
        return to_string(m_spindleSpeed);
    }
};

class DISK : public DataStorageDevice
{
private:
    size_t m_writeSpeed;

public:
    string GetWriteSpeed()
    {
        return to_string(m_writeSpeed);
    }
};

class Application
{
private:
    vector<DataStorageDevice*> m_devices;

public:
    void Add(DataStorageDevice* device)
    {
        m_devices.push_back(device);
    }

    void Delete(int position)
    {
        m_devices.erase(m_devices.begin() + position);
    }

    DataStorageDevice* Search(DeviceCharacteristics charecteristic, string data)
    {
        if(charecteristic == SPEED)
        {
            for (const auto &element : m_devices)
            {
                if (typeid(element) == typeid(USB))
                {
                    if(dynamic_cast<USB*>(element)->GetSpeed() == data)
                        return element;
                }
            }
        }
        if (charecteristic == WRITESPEED)
        {
            for (const auto &element : m_devices)
            {
                if (typeid(element) == typeid(DISK))
                {
                    if (dynamic_cast<DISK*>(element)->GetWriteSpeed() == data)
                        return element;
                }
            }
        }
        if (charecteristic == SPINDLESPEED)
        {
            for (const auto &element : m_devices)
            {
                if (typeid(element) == typeid(DVD))
                {
                    if (dynamic_cast<DVD*>(element)->GetSpindleSpeed() == data)
                        return element;
                }
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ваши классы делают одно и тоже, зачем вам наследование?

Comment: Это учебная задача: Разработать программу, которая формирует список
носителей информации, таких как, USB-флеш-накопитель,
портативный жесткий диск, DVD–диск. Каждый носитель
информации является объектом соответствующего класса:
 класс «USB-флеш-накопитель»;
 класс «Портативный жесткий диск»;
 класс «DVD–диск».
Все три класса являются производными от абстрактного
базового класса «Носитель информации».

Comment: @AnastasiiaMelnyk, я правильно понял что у вас в одной куче лежат разные носители информации и вы хотите найти в этой куче устройство у которого есть, например, `SPINDLESPEED = 42`?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, все верно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Итак. Если у вас в коде появился участок, который делает разные действия в зависимости от реального типа объекта, значит что-то пошло не так. А именно, вы не используете полиморфизм, там где ему самое место.

Давайте определим что должно уметь абстрактное устройство:

```
class DataStorageDevice{
public:
    virtual bool hasCharacteristic(DeviceCharacteristics type) const = 0;
    virtual std::string characteristic(DeviceCharacteristics type) const = 0;
    virtual ~DataStorageDevice(){}
};
```

Во-первых, оно должно уметь сказать, есть ли у него определенная характеристика. Во-вторых, вернуть значение этой характеристики. Обратите внимание на наличие виртуального деструктора. Он должен быть обязательно.

Теперь реализуем класс `USB`:

```
class USB : public DataStorageDevice{
    std::size_t _speed;
public:
    explicit USB(std::size_t speed):
        _speed(speed)
    {}
    bool hasCharacteristic(DeviceCharacteristics type) const{
        switch(type){
            case SPEED:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        };
    }
    std::string characteristic(DeviceCharacteristics type) const{
        switch(type){
            case SPEED:
                return std::to_string(_speed);
            default:
                return std::string();
        };
    }
};
```

Тут, вроде, все понятно. Аналогичным образом реализуем остальные классы.

Теперь поиск. Я, как большой любитель stl, воспользуюсь `std::find_if`:

```
struct IsDeviceCharacteristicEqual{
    DeviceCharacteristics type;
    std::string value;
    IsDeviceCharacteristicEqual(const DeviceCharacteristics type,
                                const std::string &value):
        type(type),
        value(value)
    {}
    bool operator()(const DataStorageDevice *device) const{
        if(!device->hasCharacteristic(type)){
            return false;    
        }

        return device->characteristic(type) == value;
    }
};

DataStorageDevice* search(const std::vector<DataStorageDevice*> &devices, 
                          DeviceCharacteristics type, 
                          const std::string &value){
    typedef std::vector<DataStorageDevice*>::const_iterator ConstIterator;
    ConstIterator device = std::find_if(devices.begin(), devices.end(), IsDeviceCharacteristicEqual(type, value));

    if(device == devices.end()){
        return nullptr;
    }

    return *device;
}
```

[Полный пример](http://cpp.sh/4ylga)